# EntityFramework 4 OrderBy overwrites previous OrderBy calls

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I often want to provide orderings for IQueryables that should act like secondary orderings if another is specified later.  For example, the following:

```
Repository.All.OrderBy(o => o.Name).OrderBy(o => o.SerialNumber)  [A]
```

Should be equivalent to:

```
Repository.All.OrderBy(o => o.SerialNumber).ThenBy(o => o.Name)
```

This worked correctly using LINQ to SQL.  However, in EntityFramework 4, the Order-By clause in the generated SQL looks like this:

```
ORDER BY [Project1].[SerialNumber] ASC
```

It completely ignores the first OrderBy statement, which actually breaks OrderBy being a stable sort.  ThenBy is not an option for me, because the orderings are not always defined in the same place (for example, in statement `[A]` above, the `OrderBy(o => o.Name)` could be defined in the Repository.  Extensions to `IQueryable<TModel>` are not a good solution either, because it doesn't allow different Repositories to sort differently, and the consuming code should not have to call some `.SortDefault()` code since that's not its concern.

Is there any good way to force Linq to Entities to respect multiple OrderBy statements?

Thanks

Comment: Post it on http://connect.microsoft.com/ and add link to the new bug report to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's not the most elegant solution, but I was able to overcome this in a way that seems to work fine, although I suspect all the funky reflection may make it too slow.  I created my own custom IQueryable class and associated query provider that take an ExpressionVisitor and call .Visit() on that visitor on GetEnumerator and Execute calls.  My base repository class returns a new MappedExpressionQuery and passes it the query returned from DbContext.Set() along with an ExpressionVisitor that produces the desired ordering.  The custom queryable and provider classes:

```
public class MappedExpressionQuery<T> : IOrderedQueryable<T>
{
  private IQueryable<T> baseQuery;
  private MappedExpressionQueryProvider<T> provider;

  public MappedExpressionQuery(IQueryable<T> query, ExpressionVisitor expressionMap)
  {
    baseQuery = query;
    provider = new MappedExpressionQueryProvider<T>(query.Provider, expressionMap);
  }

  #region IOrderedQueryable<T> Members

  public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
  {
    return baseQuery.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(provider.ExpressionMap.Visit(baseQuery.Expression)).GetEnumerator();
  }

  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
  {
    return baseQuery.Provider.CreateQuery(provider.ExpressionMap.Visit(baseQuery.Expression)).GetEnumerator();
  }

  public Type ElementType
  {
    get { return baseQuery.ElementType; }
  }

  public Expression Expression
  {
    get { return baseQuery.Expression; }
  }

  public IQueryProvider Provider
  {
    get { return provider; }
  }

  #endregion
}

public class MappedExpressionQueryProvider<T> : IQueryProvider
{
  public ExpressionVisitor ExpressionMap { get; private set; }
  private IQueryProvider baseProvider;

  public MappedExpressionQueryProvider(IQueryProvider baseProvider, ExpressionVisitor expressionMap)
  {
    this.ExpressionMap = expressionMap;
    this.baseProvider = baseProvider;
  }

  #region IQueryProvider Members

  public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
  {
    return new MappedExpressionQuery<TElement>(baseProvider.CreateQuery<TElement>(expression), ExpressionMap);
  }

  public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

  public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
  {
    return baseProvider.Execute<TResult>(ExpressionMap.Visit(expression));
  }

  public object Execute(Expression expression)
  {
    return baseProvider.Execute(ExpressionMap.Visit(expression));
  }

  #endregion
}
```

When my custom ExpressionVisitor class finds an OrderBy or ThenBy statement, it travels down the expression tree recording the proper orders each sort should be in until it finds a statement that is not an Order statement and is not commutative with an Order statement.  Then it builds up all the statements again at the end of the expression.  So `OrderBy(A).ThenBy(B).OrderBy(C).OrderBy(D).ThenBy(E)` is returned with the following additional expressions attached to the end: `.OrderBy(D).ThenBy(E).ThenBy(C).ThenBy(A).ThenBy(B)`.  Yes, it is redundant, but EntityFramework ignores the expressions further down the chain anyway, and I only use this QueryProvider with queryables that come from the DbContext.  The code for this expression visitor (I also threw in a fix for the fact that .ToString() doesn't translate to SQL even when used on constants, so `DbContext.Set<T>().Where(o => o.Name == SomeConstant.ToString())` works now):

```
public abstract class QueryModifier : ExpressionVisitor
{
  private bool OrganizedOrdering { get; set; }

  protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
  {
    if (node.Method.Name == "ToString" && node.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(object))
    {
      try
      {
        //If the object calling ToString is parameterless, invoke the method and convert it into a constant.
        return Expression.Constant(Expression.Lambda(node).Compile().DynamicInvoke());
      }
      catch (InvalidOperationException)
      {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("ToString() can only be translated into SQL when used on parameterless expressions.");
      }
    }
    else if (IsOrderStatement(node.Method))
    {
      if (!OrganizedOrdering)
      {
        OrganizedOrdering = true;
        return RearrangeOrderStatements(node);
      }
      else
        return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
    }
    else if (OrganizedOrdering && !IsOrderCommutative(node.Method))
    {
      OrganizedOrdering = false;
      return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
    }
    else
    {
      return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
    }
  }

  private Expression RearrangeOrderStatements(MethodCallExpression node)
  {
    //List to store (OrderBy expression, position) tuples
    List<Tuple<MethodCallExpression, double>> orderByExpressions = new List<Tuple<MethodCallExpression, double>>();
    double low = 0;
    double high = 1;

    MethodCallExpression startNode = node;
    Expression lastNode = node.Arguments[0];

    //Travel down the chain and store all OrderBy and ThenBy statements found with their relative positions
    while (node != null && node.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(System.Linq.Queryable))
    {
      if (node.Arguments.Count == 0)
        break;

      if (node.Method.Name.StartsWith("OrderBy"))
      {
        orderByExpressions.Add(new Tuple<MethodCallExpression, double>(node, low));
        low = low + 1;
        high = low + 1;
      }
      else if (node.Method.Name.StartsWith("ThenBy"))
      {
        double pos = (high - low) * 0.9 + low;
        orderByExpressions.Add(new Tuple<MethodCallExpression, double>(node, pos));
        high = pos;
      }
      else if (!IsOrderCommutative(node.Method))
      {
        break;
      }

      lastNode = node.Arguments[0];
      node = lastNode as MethodCallExpression;
    }

    lastNode = startNode;
    var methods = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().Where(o => IsOrderStatement(o));

    Type queryType = startNode.Arguments[0].Type.GetGenericArguments()[0];

    bool firstStatement = true;
    foreach (var tuple in orderByExpressions.OrderBy(o => o.Item2))
    {
      string methodName;
      if (firstStatement)
      {
        methodName = "OrderBy";
        firstStatement = false;
      }
      else
        methodName = "ThenBy";
      if (tuple.Item1.Method.Name.EndsWith("Descending"))
        methodName = methodName + "Descending";

      Type orderByTValueType = tuple.Item1.Arguments[1].Type.GetGenericArguments()[0].GetGenericArguments()[1];

      if (tuple.Item1.Arguments.Count == 3)
      {
        var method = methods.Single(o => o.Name == methodName && o.GetParameters().Length == 3)
          .MakeGenericMethod(queryType, orderByTValueType);
        lastNode = Expression.Call(method, lastNode, tuple.Item1.Arguments[1], tuple.Item1.Arguments[2]);
      }
      else
      {
        var method = methods.Single(o => o.Name == methodName && o.GetParameters().Length == 2)
          .MakeGenericMethod(queryType, orderByTValueType);
        lastNode = Expression.Call(method, lastNode, tuple.Item1.Arguments[1]);
      }
    }

    return Visit(lastNode);
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Returns true if the given method call expression is commutative with OrderBy statements.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="expression"></param>
  /// <returns></returns>
  private bool IsOrderCommutative(MethodInfo method)
  {
    return new string[] { "Where", "Distinct", "AsQueryable" }.Contains(method.Name)
      && method.DeclaringType == typeof(System.Linq.Queryable);
  }

  private bool IsOrderStatement(MethodInfo method)
  {
    return (method.Name.StartsWith("OrderBy") || method.Name.StartsWith("ThenBy"))
      && method.DeclaringType == typeof(System.Linq.Queryable);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't agree that a subsequent `OrderBy` should be equivalent to a `ThenBy`. If that were so, there would be no need for `ThenBy` and you could never override an existing sort.

I can't say I like it, but off the top of my head this would seem an option for downstream sorting:

```
IQueryable<Item> items = Repository.GetAllWhichMightBeOrderedAlready();
return items is IOrderedEnumerable<Item>
    ? ((IOrderedQueryable<Item>)items).ThenBy(x => x.SomeProperty)
    : items.OrderBy(x => x.SomeProperty);
```

Substitute `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` as appropriate.

Comment: You misunderstood my question.  OrderBy is supposed to be a stable sort, which means that if two records have the same spot in the ordering, they maintain their original order.  If I do OrderBy(A).OrderBy(B), that should be equivalent to OrderBy(B).ThenBy(A), since the "original order" was A.  I am not saying a subsequent OrderBy should be equivalent to ThenBy; it certainly should not.  Your answer doesn't work because it only provides a secondary ordering, while I am trying to add a primary ordering on top of the original.

Answer (score 0):

So you can't use ThenBy because the initial OrderBy might be skipped?  How about doing an initial dummy OrderBy, then all the others are ThenBy.

```
// Basically, everything gets the same orderby ranking
// I don't know offhand if you can use a constant here, but if you have an id,
// you should be able to this.
var list = context.MyTable.OrderBy(mt => mt.id - mt.id);

if (order by field1)
    list = list.ThenBy(mt => mt.field1);

if (order by field2)
    list = list.ThenBy(mt => mt.field2);
```

etc...

EDIT: Nevermind. This doesn't work.  Can't use ThenBy on a seperate line by itself, as I was thinking.